# Ordering a dictionary with a certain culture in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

With the following Dictionary in C#:

```
Dictionary<char, int> di1 = new Dictionary<char, int>();
```

How do you order by using certain culture as follows:

```
CultureInfo ci = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("es-ES");
bool ignoreCase = true;
StringComparer comp = StringComparer.Create(ci, ignoreCase);
var ordered = di1.OrderBy(x => x.Key, comp); // <-- Error in this line
```

It is giving me an error in the order by :

```
... cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly...
```

Thanks before hand.

Comment: Try `x => x.Key.ToString()`

Answer (score 3):

`StringComparer` compares *strings*.

You need to convert `.Key` from `char` to `string`, by calling `.ToString()`.

Comment: Thanks!  I cant believe I missed that. :)